# Saving indexed 16-bit grayscale png in C#

Tags: c#, png, indexed

I don't know if GDI+ supports saving a bitmap to 16-bit grayscale indexed png, but if it does I can't seem to be able to do it. Is this possible? If not, is there an open-source library that can be used?

Comment: Grayscale isn't indexed. Indexed means the pixels refer to indices on a colour palette. Grayscale images just have values that give a brightness directly, without any palette involved. That said, GDI+ doesn't contain any support for 16-bit grayscale, no. It is listed in the `PixelFormat` enum (as `Format16bppGrayScale`), but it is not actually supported.

Answer (score 1):

[AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm) contains a grayscale library... you might check to see if this meets your needs.